# Powershell recursively move 20,000 files at a time

Tags: powershell, batch-file, increment, move

I'm a novice with Powershell.  I'm trying to move data to be processed elsewhere that has limitations on the number of files at a time it can handle.  My source folder has hundreds of subfolders that each in turn may also have up to 100 subfolders, totaling up to millions of small files.  File names are assumed to be unique 25-digit output from an export so checking existing file names at each move will not be necessary if excluding the check speeds up the overall process.

I'd like to automate moving (not copy) these with Powershell from source path to an incremental named destination folder of 20,000 files each.  The destination output folder names are not important as long as they each only have no more than 20,000 files in each destination and don't overlap existing folder names.

Example:

Source : C:\MyFiles has 100 subfolders that each also have 100 subfolders.

`C:\Myfiles\Folder000\Folder000A\file1.txt`
`C:\Myfiles\Folder000\Folder000A\file2.txt`
`C:\Myfiles\Folder000\Folder000A\file3.txt`
`C:\Myfiles\Folder000\Folder000B\file1.txt`
`C:\Myfiles\Folder000\Folder000B\file1.txt`
`C:\Myfiles\Folder001\Folder000A\file1.txt`
`...etc`

Destination D:\My20Kfiles

`D:\My20kFiles\000001 [20,000 messages]`
`D:\My20kFiles\000002 [next 20,000 messages]`
`D:\My20kFiles\000003 [next 20,000 messages]`
`...etc`

Comment: Do eyou get an idea when you execute `gci |select -first 10` ;-)

Comment: Right but how can I loop through that output one line at a time to move it to destination?  I know I can get the full path to output to screen with -first like get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.txt -file | select -first 10000 | % { $_.FullName }

Comment: To clarify: you're fine with _flattening_ the input hierarchy on moving the files to the target folders? That is at odds with your sample data, which has non-unique filenames, such as `file1.txt`

Comment: I have modified the code to pass logfile filename with path and $testmode=$false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $yourdir="C:\MyFiles"
 $yourdestdir="D:\My20Kfiles"
 $loop=20000
 $i=$loop;
 gci $yourdir -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt  | %{$newdir="$yourdestdir\{0:d6}\" -f [math]::DivRem($i++, $loop, [ref]$null)   ;new-item -Path $newdir -Force -ItemType Directory; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Dest $newdir -Force }
```

Comment: Ran and instantaneously returned to prompt with no output and appeared to take no actions on a test sample copy directory used for $yourdir

Comment: have you files .txt into your dir C:\MyFiles  ? it work on my test

Comment: And there was my mistake I neglected to correct the extension!  Thank you this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

List the files, move them to a folder named (counter++ / 20000).

```
gci "c:\myfiles" -R -File | mv -Dest {"c:\My20kFiles\{0:d6}\" -f [math]::DivRem($global:counter++, 20000, [ref]$null)} -Force -WhatIf
```

Untested. Ymmv. mv will create folders with -Force. Remove `-WhatIf` to make it actually run.

It doesn't actually check for 20k files in a folder, or whether it's overlapping existing folder names. But the principle applies, I guess.

Also untested, this tries to put 20k files in a folder, then move on to the next unused folder number.

```
$FolderNumber = 0
$FilesRemainingForThisFolder = 0

Get-ChildItem "c:\myfiles" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {

    if (0 -eq $FilesRemainingForThisFolder)
    {
        # Keep counting foldernumber until we get to a folder name that doesn't exist.
        do {
            $FolderNumber++
            $DestinationFolder = "c:\My20kFiles\{0:d6}\" -f $FolderNumber
        } while ((Test-Path $DestinationFolder))

        mkdir $DestinationFolder
        $FilesRemainingForThisFolder = 19999
    }
    else
    {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force -WhatIf
        $FilesRemainingForThisFolder--
    }

}
```

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- [`Test-Path`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113418) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- [`Move-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)

Comment: Nicely done; didn't know about the pass-a-script-block-as-a-parameter-value-evaluated-with-the-current-pipeline-object-as-a-parameter trick. (Where is that documented?) I suggest `[Math]::Floor()` as a simpler alternative to `[Math]::DivRem()` (at least in this case, for positive results, if there's no need for the remainder).

Comment: @mklement0 do you know about it in the context of `sort-object`? e.g. `gci | sort -property { $_.substring(3,5) }` to sort files by a part of the name? I have no idea where it's documented, although this blog post  - https://learn-powershell.net/2014/10/11/using-a-scriptblock-parameter-with-a-powershell-function/ - MVP Dave Wyatt, in the comments, says it isn't well documented, and talks about how it works. Edit: Jeffrey Snover blogs that it happens here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/23/flexible-pipelining-with-scriptblock-parameters/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, here an `-ea sil..` is needed and to see an effect `gci | sort -property { $_.Name.substring(1,1) } -ea silentlycontinue`

Comment: @LotPings point; I usually use it with a regex replace, where there is no error when it fails, e.g. `gci | sort { $_.Name -replace '^prefix[123]' }` or similar. Also things like `gci | sort { Get-Random }` are possible, where the scriptblock doesn't reference the filename at all.

Comment: Thanks for the great background info. Jeffrey Snover's post (from 2006!) is _obsolete_, because it claims that you can use the feature - which he simply calls _ScriptBlock Parameters_ - 
only with _non_-pipeline parameters, but since - at least - PSv2 it works only for parameters that ARE designed for pipeline input.
Therefore, `Sort-Object` is an anomaly, because its `-Property` parameter is _not_ designed to take pipeline input (although it otherwise works the same: the current pipeline object is passed to the script block).

Comment: In short: the feature works generically for parameters that take pipeline input - whether by value or property name - if those parameters aren't explicitly typed as script blocks or untyped or typed as `[object]`.
What makes it powerful is that the script block you pass is invoked (with `$_` bound to the current pipeline object) even if the parameter wouldn't ordinarily be bound. Your `mv` (`Move-Item`) command is an example of that:
the script block is invoked, even though the `-Destination` parameter ordinarily binds only to input objects that have a `Destination` property.

Comment: The single line appears ok when WhatIf runs however without it I get:
mv : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:1 char:51
Checking the destination folder it is empty.

Comment: Running the longer scripted version has similar results that it can't write when that file already exists.  It moves one file into the destination folder as 000001 (no extention) then continues through scrolling errors for each file that it is unable to write.

Comment: I guess I was too optimistic saying that `mv` will create the folder, it won't. I've edited the longer form one so it does, but it's probably irrelevant now there's an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is testable and do the following tasks:

Check if target folder is empty, exit if it's not.

Log the moving files action to a file named log.txt  to be latter reviewed.

Can work in test mode to know in advance what is will happen.

You can define the source folder -target folder - increment value

```
   function Move-Files {
     param ($Source ,$Targert,$Increment=5 , $TestMode, $Logfile)

        $currentpath=pwd
        if (!$LogFile) {$Logfile= "{0}\{1}" -f $currentpath,"log.txt" }
        "log file is created in $logfile"  
        # check that destination folder is empty and create 
         if(!(Test-Path -Path $Targert )){
                  $null=New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Targert -Force
          }
         else 
         {
          $targetFiles = get-childitem $Targert -Recurse  -File
          if ($targetFiles -ne $null) {"Target folder not empty, Please remove it";return}
         }


        $files=get-childitem $source -Recurse  -File    
        $fileCounter=0
        $folderCounter=0
        $Nextfolder="00001"
        "Moving {0} to {1}| Total Files: {2} | Increment:{3}" -f $Source, $Targert , $files.count,$increment |tee  $Logfile
        $files  |foreach {
          $fileCounter++ 
          if ((($fileCounter - 1) % $increment) -eq 0)
          { 
               $folderCounter++ 
               $Nextfolder= "{0}\{1}" -f $targert, $folderCounter.ToString("000000")    
               "Creating new folder {0}  at counter={1}" -f $Nextfolder,$fileCounter |tee -Append $Logfile
               #create Folder 
                $null=New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Nextfolder -Force

              }
              if ($testMode)
              {
                "mv {0}  {1}" -f $_.FullName,$Nextfolder  |tee -Append $Logfile 
              }
              else
              {

                mv $_.FullName -Destination  $Nextfolder  -Force  #-WhatIf
                "mv {0}  {1}" -f $_.FullName,$Nextfolder  |tee -Append $Logfile
              }
        }
    }
```

**How to use:**

```
    $source="i:\myfiles"
    $targert="i:\My20kFiles"
    $increment=5  # for a test, modify 20000

     #run in test mode to know what will happen
     $TestMode=$true # modify to $flase to actual moving files

     Move-Files  -Source $source -Targert $targert  -Increment  $increment -TestMode $TestMode
```

Sample of output: (you find the same out in the log file log.txt)

```
    Moving i:\myfiles to i:\My20kFiles| Total Files: 42 | Increment:5
    Creating new folder i:\My20kFiles\000001  at counter=1
    mv I:\myfiles\1.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000001
    mv I:\myfiles\10.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000001
    mv I:\myfiles\11.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000001
    mv I:\myfiles\12.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000001
    mv I:\myfiles\13.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000001
    Creating new folder i:\My20kFiles\000002  at counter=6
    mv I:\myfiles\14.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000002
    mv I:\myfiles\15.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000002
    mv I:\myfiles\16.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000002
    mv I:\myfiles\17.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000002
    mv I:\myfiles\18.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000002
    Creating new folder i:\My20kFiles\000003  at counter=11
    mv I:\myfiles\19.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000003
    mv I:\myfiles\2.txt  i:\My20kFiles\000003
    .................
```

**Update:**

I modified the code:
Add logfile as a parameter. The default path will be the current powershell working folder

$Testmode is initially false, so you move files. You can pass the parameter $Testmode=$true to run in test mode (no moving to the files) and you can review the log file which describe where the files will be moved.

You can customize the code as you wish

Comment: Flattening 20k files into a new single folder for each set is the result I'd like to have.  Thank you for the options - I will be attempting both of these examples and will get back with results shortly.

Comment: I'm probably not using your code correctly.  I've saved it and executed with variables set into the script and executed with arguments and get no output and no log.txt

Comment: The log.txt is created in the default path of ISE. You can define a path e.g c:\temp\log.txt. Set $testmode=$false to move files. if $testmode=$true (the default) no moving to files but log.txt is created with messages describing the files move source and targe. Try and let me know the result.